# How to represent json array in XSD

Tags: arrays, xml, json, xsd

I have the below json , how can it be represented in XSD. It is a json tuple i could not find a valid construct in XSD to represent this type of json structure.

```
{
"type": "array",
"items": [
{
"type": "number"
},
{
"type": "string"
},
{
"type": "string",
"enum": ["Street", "Avenue", "Boulevard"]
},
{
"type": "string",
"enum": ["NW", "NE", "SW", "SE"]
}
]
}
```

Comment: Why do you imagine XSD should be capable of describing JSON structures?

Comment: @user2478236 Have you looked [here in the section titled **Example for JSON Object message containing a JSON array**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/sm12023_.htm?lang=en)?

Comment: Michael Kay , I need to convert between XSD and JSON schemas.

Answer (score 2):

It would help others if you would provide more context to your question. First, your example is from page 30 (print version) of the [Understanding JSON Schema](http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/) guide. Your JSON is a JSON schema (draft #4).

Because you're talking about schemas, I take your question as being about models. To be even clearer, I consider your question similar to one asked many years back: can one use UML to represent an XSD structure?

I actually do use XSD to describe JSON structures; we have an automatic conversion between XSD and JSON schemas (draft #4), since I use myself XSD as a data modeling language.

Your particular example has no natural XSD equivalent. By natural, I mean one that would make sense as XML as well, and which a "generic" XML-to-JSON transformation would yield an expected result.

If we take away simple things, such as a simple type modeled as a list:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="array">
    <xsd:list itemType="xsd:float"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

which basically is the same as (except for the comma separator):

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "number"
    }
}
```

then my answer is really about a "profile" that will be used by a conversion tool to take the semantics of a model represented in XSD (in other words, we're not hung up on XML documents here), into the same represented using JSON schema.

Our XSD-to-JSON schema profile uses a complex type to represent objects and arrays. When the "stereotype" applied to a complex type is "array", then the following model perfectly matches your JSON schema.

```
<xsd:complexType name="address">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <xsd2json:type>array</xsd2json:type>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="StreetNumber" type="xsd:float"/>
        <xsd:element name="StreetName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="StreetType">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Street"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Avenue"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Boulevard"/>                        
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="StreetDirection">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="NW"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="NE"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SW"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SE"/>                       
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: yes its from the json schema guide , i have requirements  for converting json schema to XSD for integration products.Is there any git hub project or open source project that does this.During conversions should we make up the element names.

Comment: Most of the times, you will not have to make up names; for this particular example, yes. I said "most" since indeed, the JSON schema paper shows a good example of a heterogeneous array; it is bad though, by most data modeling standards. It is compact, yes. Instance documents would not be that readable though... I am not aware of any open source projects that do what I described.